# foreach() loop for each 3 items

Tags: php

I would like a loop to repeat on every 3 items results. I am reading a folder containing .jpg and would like to group them in group of 3.

So the result would look like this :

```
<div>
   <img src="1.jpg"/>
   <img src="2.jpg"/>
   <img src="3.jpg"/>
</div>
<div>
   <img src="4.jpg"/>
   <img src="5.jpg"/>
   <img src="6.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing because I have no clue that's why I ask how to achieve this.

Comment: You knew enough to mention `foreach()`. Maybe if you actually read around that doc page...

Comment: add the php array to the question

Comment: Hint: Think about using a counter and modular logic (i%3 == 0)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data will always be exactly in multiples of 3's:

```
   for ($i = 0; $i < $numTotal; $i += 3) {
        echo '<div>
               <img src="' . $i + 1 . '.jpg"/>
               <img src="' . $i + 2 . '.jpg"/>
               <img src="' . $i + 3 . '.jpg"/>
              </div>';  
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you have already gotten the array of files:

```
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div>';
    foreach ($array as $images) {

         echo '<img src="'.$images.'.jpg" />';
         if ($count%3==0) echo '</div><div>'; 
         $count++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution:

```
<?php

$my_array = array();

$my_array[] = "1.jpg";
$my_array[] = "2.jpg";
$my_array[] = "3.jpg";
$my_array[] = "4.jpg";
$my_array[] = "5.jpg";
$my_array[] = "6.jpg";


$content = "";

$i = 0;

foreach($my_array as $img_name)
    {

    if($i === 0)
        {       
                $content .= "<div>";
        }

        $content .= "<img src=\"" . $img_name . "\"/>"; 

    $i++;

    if($i === 3)
        {
            $content .= "</div>";   
            $i = 0; 
        }
    }

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of the modulo to group by smaller/greater sizes

```
echo "<div>";
for($i=1;$i<=$maxImg;$i++) {
  echo "<img src=\"".${i}.".jpg\"/>";
  if(mod($i,3) == 0 && $i < $maxImg) {
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div>";
    }
  }
echo "</div>";
```